# How to make blur effect when view controller slides out

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I've got a program with slide out menu. There's Menu button(BarButtonItem) in the right position. When the view controller loads I'm doing next

```
_menuBarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
_menuBarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
```

So, when I click on the this button the View Controller slides out to right and I see another View Controller.

So, I want to make the main view controller blur when it slides out. I've got a code how to do it blur, but I can't implement this code because when I tap on the bat button it runs revealToggle: selector.

I've tried:
1. To set action for bar button. And firstly blur view controller:

```
- (IBAction)menuBarButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self setBlurEffect];
    _menuBarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _menuBarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
    [self.menuBarButton.target performSelector:@selector(revealToggle:)];
}
```

But app crashes with "unrecognized selector" (the solutions of this problem doesn
t help too).

2. I've wanted to use willDisapear method but it doesn't run, because the main view controller doesn't disapear. It just slides out.

So, could you help me with this problem?

P.S. I'll be happy if you propose any other effects for main view controller except blur.
P.P.S. Sorry for many mistakes in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a good answer for me. I don't use several ViewControllers to implement menu panel.
Now I'm using another UIView calls menuPanel. It contains tableView(UITableView) and blurView(UIView). The second one is under first one.
You can blur this view in to ways:

1. From the code using next method.

   ```
        (void) setBlurEffect {// Add blur view

       CGRect boundsView = self.someView.bounds;
   UIVisualEffectView *tableViewVisualEffect = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight]];

       self.tableViewVisualEffect.frame = boundsView;
       self.tableViewVisualEffect.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
       self.tableViewVisualEffect.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

       [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                         duration:0.3
                          options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                       animations: ^ {
                           [self.someView addSubview:self.tableViewVisualEffect];
                       }
                       completion: nil ];


       // Here you can add visual effects to any UIView control.
       // Replace custom view with navigation bar in above code to add effects to custom view.
   }
   ```

Where someView is view you want to do blur(or any other effect)

2. From the story board with Visual Effect View.(I've chosen)

After all I've set tableView and blurView into menuPanelView as pinned to all sides of the menuPanel with 0 distance.

And the last thing I've done I'm changing the position of the menuPanelView with animation:

```
        [self.menuPanelView setFrame:self.visibleTableViewFramePosition];

         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                          animations:^{
                     [self.menuPanelView setFrame:self.invisibleTableViewFramePosition];
         } completion:nil];
```

Where `invisibleTableViewFramePosition` is CGRect variable contains position of the menuPanelView when it has to be invisible. You also need to create visibleTableViewFramePosition.

That's all. Hope it may be helpful for someone=)